# Use iOS SwipeGesture To Cycle through UIButtons

Tags: ios, loops, uibutton, hidden, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have 6 UIButtons set up in my UIView, all in the exact same location.  What I want to do, is to swipe from left to right or right to left, in order to go through the buttons.

I have the UIGestures all set up and working on the view, I am just not sure the best way to go about cycling through these UIButtons.

I was thinking that it could be simple enough to tag each UIButton and HIDE all but one, but am not sure about the best way to loop through these.

Comment: Simply add them into an array and keep the index of the current selected one

Comment: Some code to help out...anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put them in an `NSMutableArray` and whatever button is at index 0 is the visible one, as they swipe you'd remove the button at index 0, set it to `hidden = YES` and add it to the end of the array then set the button at index 0's `hidden = NO`.

Assuming you're using ARC, inside your class' implementation (.m) file:

```
@interface MyFancyButtonClass () {
    NSMutableArray *_swipeButtons;
}
```

inside your `viewDidLoad`:

```
_swipeButtons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour, nil];
buttonOne.hidden = NO;
buttonTwo.hidden = buttonThree.hidden = buttonFour.hidden = YES;
```

inside your gestureRecognizer:

```
UIButton *currentVisibleButton = [_swipeButtons firstObject];
UIButton *nextVisibleButton = [_swipeButtons objectAtIndex:1];

[_swipeButtons removeObject:currentVisibleButton];
[_swipeButtons addObject:currentVisibleButton];

currentVisibleButton.hidden = YES;
nextVisibleButton.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: You could also animate them fading out by setting there .alpha = 0 in an animation block.

Comment: Agreed, that'd be the slick way of doing it.

Comment: How do you add buttons to a mutable array and how to you change all these things.

Comment: I kind of get what you're saying, but there's little to go on.

Comment: I have ` self.buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:map, boardmembers, facebook, twitter, lessonbooks, schedule, nil];` but am not sure about what to do with the array now.

Comment: Sure thing, I updated the answer, my answer implies that the 1st item in the _swipeButtons is the visible button.

Comment: I think I understand, but Xcode gives me an error on that last line.  Says property hidden not found on object of type 'id'...regarding `[_swipeButtons firstObject].hidden = NO;

Comment: Updated the answer, you could also solve it by doing `((UIButton *)[_swipeButtons firstObject]).hidden = NO` but I went with using more descriptive variable names instead.

Comment: Would it be possible to do something in reverse for a different method when the swipe gesture recognizer for the opposite direction is called?

Comment: Yes, just add/remove the items you need from _swipeButtons, the functions you'd be interested in are `[_swipeButtons lastObject]` to get the last item and `[_swipeButtons insertObject:button atIndex:0]` to put a button on top of the stack instead of the bottom.

Comment: I have added for that gesture `UIButton *currentVisibleButton = [_buttonArray lastObject];
    UIButton *nextVisibleButton = [_buttonArray objectAtIndex:0];
    
    [_buttonArray removeObject:currentVisibleButton];
    [_buttonArray addObject:currentVisibleButton];
    
    currentVisibleButton.hidden = YES;
    nextVisibleButton.hidden = NO;` but it didn't do anything other than print the log in the console.

Comment: I still cannot figure out how to get it to go backwards. @Shizam

Answer (score 0):

Create a NSMutableArray like this:

```
NSMutableArray * buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[buttons addObject:button1];
[buttons addObject:button2];
[buttons addObject:button3];
[buttons addObject:button4];
[buttons addObject:button5];
```

Save this array to a property like this

```
self.buttons = buttons;
```

Store the currentButton Like this:

```
int currentButton = 0;
```

Get the current button like this:

```
UIButton * currentSelectedButton = buttons[currentButton];
```

Cycle through the buttons like this:

```
UIButton * currentSelectedButton = buttons[currentButton];
currentSelectedButton.hidden = YES;
currentButton++;
if (currentButton >= self.buttons.count)
    currentButton = 0;
currentSelectedButton = buttons[currentButton];
currentSelectedButton.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: Not sure if this works for my setup.   I use .xib and not storyboard.  The 6 buttons are laid out on my view, all in the same coordinates and size.  I have two GestureRecognizers set up, one for left swipe and one for right swipe.  They each call a different IBAction set up in my code.

Comment: Create the array in ViewDidLoad: Connect all your buttons as IBOutlets to your code and you're good to go. If you're feeling adventurous, create a IBOutletCollection and your array of buttons is automatically created for you!